# Need formal definition for "question that has no upvoted answers"

Tags: support, user-interface, unanswered-questions

In all likelihood I'm missing something about the notion of what exactly an *answered question* actually is, ..or there seems to be a bug in the counter.

Go to **Questions**/*unanswered*, you get 996 "questions that have no upvoted answers":

[image]

---

Go to **Unanswered**/*votes*, you get 992 "questions with no upvoted answers":

[image]

---

**Why is there a difference in the two figures?**

Answer (score 5):

Let's try to answer the question *with science*. I created [a simple web scraper](https://gist.github.com/svick/7626527) (yeah, scraping is usually a bad idea when there is API available, but I don't think that's an option here).

Trying to ignore some weirdness in the results (probably caused by caching, or something like that; see below), I found out that there are 4 questions that are in questions/unanswered, but not in unanswered/votes (which exactly matches the difference  between 996 and 992):

- [Speed up SVN backup](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24025/speed-up-svn-backup)
- [Small PHP framework template library](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30304/small-php-framework-almost-one-year-later)
- [Speed up MySQL query with IN clause](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26974/speed-up-mysql-query-with-in-clause-to-much)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19399/my-first-comprehensive-solution-c-datadriven-web-appication-ft-my-html-ma

What these questions have in common is that they have **negative vote score**. It looks to me like those are the only four unclosed unanswered questions with negative score, which would explain the difference.

---

The actual results, were, well, weird.

First, among the, say, 992 questions, the number of distinct questions was sometimes 942, sometimes 892 and sometimes even 942. Since it's always a multiple of the page size (50) less, this leads me to believe that the order of pages is not always consistent and that a certain page can appear at at least two different positions.

Second, the total number of questions/unanswered was sometimes 996, but sometimes 992. I don't understand how could this happen. (The number of unanswered/votes was always 992.)

Comment: So... we've got a bug then?

Comment: @retailcoder Not sure. The difference of 4 is probably intentional. And those 50n repeated questions might be some artifact of caching, or something like that. I'm not sure how important is it to get that right.